# Hide entire tabular row using multiaudience

Tags: tables

I am using the `multiaudience` package to create two different versions of a LaTeX document.  My document contains a `tabular` environment with a table row which I want to make visible to one audience only.  Is there a way of doing this?

The two approaches I've used below (the lines I've commented out for now) each cause errors, because the `&` and the `\\` are enclosed in the text to be shown to the audience. I can of course use `showto`'s or `shownto`'s to enclose just the text within individual table cells but this still creates a table row (i.e., any text not visible for the current audience results in a blank line in the table).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{a1}
\SetNewAudience{a2}
\DefCurrentAudience{a2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Thing1 & Thing2\\
\hline
This thing & To be seen by everyone\\
%\showto{a1}{That thing & To be seen by a1 only\\}
%\begin{shownto}{a2}Other thing & To be seen by a2 only\\\end{shownto}
Final thing & Everyone can see this too
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there

1. some way round this using `multiaudience`
2. an alternative package which will do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by moving the logic of that all into an `\omit...\cr` block. The following does so. It always starts a new row after `\tableshowto` regardless of whether you used `\\` or not. The environment variant still doesn't work with this.

And before I forget, it must be used as the first thing in a cell, but it will start a new row for its argument and after it, so it is only really meant to work on a complete row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{a1}
\SetNewAudience{a2}
%\DefCurrentAudience{a2}
\DefCurrentAudience{a1}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\newcommand\tableshowto[2]
  {%
    \omit
    \@MULTAU@shownfalse
    \@MULTAU@includetrue
    \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
    \if@MULTAU@shown
      \@afterfi{\cr#2\crcr\omit}%
    \fi
    \@MULTAU@showntrue
    \@MULTAU@includetrue
    \cr
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Thing1 & Thing2\\
\hline
This thing & To be seen by everyone\\
\tableshowto{a1}{That thing & To be seen by a1 only\\}
Final thing & Everyone can see this too
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output for `a1`:

[image: a1]

Output for `a2`:

[image: a2]